# How to modify an element that matches a condition using lenses?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm trying to write a function with the following type-signature using lenses, but staring blankly at [`filtered`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:filtered) is apparently not working!

```
modifyElem
  :: (a -> Bool)      -- predicate function
  -> (a -> a)         -- modification to apply
  -> [a]
  -> [a]
```

If possible, this could also be generalised further to the following:

```
modifyElem
  :: (Foldable t)     -- or (Traversable t)
  -> (a -> Bool)
  -> (a -> a)
  -> t a
  -> t a
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
modifyElem :: Traversable t => (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> t a -> t a
modifyElem predicate transform target =
  target & traverse . filtered predicate %~ transform
```